# jquery - Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

For my fiddle below, I am seeing the error

http://jsfiddle.net/d3qD4/23/

How to handle the decimal and spaces( right now using `.split`, `join()` - not sure if this is the right way) and avoid the unrecognized expression. any ideas?

```
$('label[title=' + $this.text().split(" ").join("") + ']').prev('input').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: When I select 14.5 or on test.com checkbox they are being added to the div below and when i click on the image they should be removed from the div - it is happening with the rest of the checkboxes but not with these two - Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [title=14.5
         ]
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
Line 3

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the attribute value in quotes:

```
$('label[title="' + $this.text().split(" ").join("") + '"]')
```

So you end up with `[title="14.5"]` instead of `[title=14.5]`

Comment: I tried that - the error updates to Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [title="14.5 "], doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you have a space at the end.. is that why you're doing the split/join? Try `$this.text().replace(/ /g, '')`

Comment: I don't have any extra space, regex does not work too: you can check on my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/d3qD4/23/

Comment: It has a newline and a whole bunch of space. This fixes the selector (`$.trim()` and the quotes): `$('label[title="' + $.trim($this.text()) + '"]')`.